# Jest: Testing random position of an array

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

After some research, I found out that *mock*ing will allow me to test random values. However, how do I test the value of a random position (needle) picked up on an array (haystack)?

For instance, how do you test this code with *Jest*?

```
var words = ['Hey', 'Hello', 'Hi'];
var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * (words.length - 1) + 0 );
var word = words[random];
```

Comment: You can't really have unit tests that have `Math.random()` in them. That means the test might work, or it might fail. Imagine the simplest case: `assertTrue(Math.random() > 0.5);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't necessarily test against `Math.random`, in this case I think this can be tested by simply checking the values.

```
function pick(words) {
  var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * (words.length - 1) + 0 );
  return words[random];
}

expect(pick(['Hey', 'Hello', 'Hi'])).toMatch(/Hey|Hello|Hi/)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` does not let you set the seed value, this will be problematic in case of testing ([check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)).

You might want to look for random number generator which can be seeded. This will help you get a repeatable set (atleast for testing). One article which might be useful is [here](http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { mock, clear } from "jest-random-mock";

beforeEach(() => {
  mock();
});

test("your test cases", () => {
  mock();
  const r1 = Math.random();
  clear();

  mock();
  const r2 = Math.random();
  clear();

  // expect r1 should be same with r2.
});

afterEach(() => {
  clear();
});
```